# Passing circular JSON to cluster in node

Tags: json, node.js, fork, sequelize.js, node-cluster

I would like to get a multi-process node, working with Sequelize.
As you can't call Sequelize's sync method to get your orm ready multiple time at once (database locking), I decided to call the sync method on the master cluster. When that's done, fork the process to match CPU count.

But I can't obviously share global variables across the forks, and if I try to pass the Sequelize variable through the environnement (http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_fork_env) or with `worker.message(data)` and `process.on` (http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_send_message_sendhandle), it won't send circular JSON..

So I'm wondering how to pass complex/circular object to a child process.

Does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: Please take a look at using ``redis`` for your work...through which you can share your application state variables in your application...

Comment: That's more than states. That's a circular JSON variable, containing functions and all

Comment: in ``redis`` you can save objects against keys..

Comment: Classic JSON objects, yes. Not circular. Not containing functions.